# Method to split value i multiple rows

Tags: excel

Hello I am looking for a method to divide a value into a number of parts with the same header information.

Starting from

[image]

With a result of

[image]

In addition to this, it should not just work with whole package amounts, if it if the value was smaller than the package size, then it should give you the remainder of the quantity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to show original effort, this is not a "code for me" site.  If you're looking to get started, you'll want to first loop through the range, a simple way is `For RowIndex = 2 to LastRow` and then have a nested loop that looks like `For i = 1 to Cells(RowIndex, "B").Value Step Cells(RowIndex, "C").Value` in order to create the pack amounts.

Comment: Shouldn't Green be 25 in the result pic?

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple macro for an example:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 2

    For i = 2 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1)
        tot = Cells(i, 2)
        pack = Cells(i, 3)
        While tot > 0
            Cells(K, 4) = v
            Cells(K, 5) = pack
            tot = tot - pack
            If tot < pack Then
                Cells(K + 1, 5) = tot
                Cells(K + 1, 4) = v
                tot = 0
            End If
            K = K + 1
        Wend
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]